# How to render a Component in JTable using TableModel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcomponent

I have successfully displayed a `JTable` using an `AbstractTableModel`, but I want to add delete button for each row in the last column, in the `getValueAt` method that returns `Object` there is no way that I can return `JButton`, `JLabel` or any `JComponent` that is clickable. I tried that and I only get the object description `toString`.

Is there another solution  to render `JComponent` in a `JTable` without using the `TableModel` approach?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson, Thank you for your help, but is this possible?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I want the functionality more than the look actually, I have used some specific  cell renderers before, thay were all about styling, not really making the cell a Container! Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another solution to render JComponent in JTable without using the TableModel approach?

The TableModel is used to hold the data for the data for the model.

The JTable implements the view of the data for each column. The renderer is just a picture of the data. You can easily render the data to look like a button, however a renderer does not respond to any event.

The JTable does support editors and that is how you interact with real components. When you edit a normal cell a JTextField is placed in the cell location so you can type data into the cell and then the data is save to the model.

So if you want to click on a button then you need to use a button as an editor.

Check out [Table Column Button](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a class that uses a JButton as the renderer and editor. You then provide the class an `Action` to be invoked when the button is clicked.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concepts: Renderers and Editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information. There is also a section on `Using Other Editors`.

Comment: *"you need to use a button as an editor"* I was *almost* about to mention editors but decided to leave it in hope of one of the table gurus replying. Glad I did. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way : TableColumn.setCellEditor(jbutton_instance) on a hand added column.